# Http.post() AJAX no response from JSP/Spring server

Tags: php, spring, jsp, angular, ionic2

In my ***Ionic 2*** app, I'm fetching data from example site `www.my-website.com/member/loginPersist.do` using this block of code :

> This *`/member/loginPersist`* is a Spring MVC controller

**login-service.ts**

```
 private GetUser(user : User): Promise<any> {
    let options = this.makeHeader("post");
    let x = this.http.post("http://my-website.com/member/loginPersist.do", this.serialize(user) ,options).toPromise().catch(this.handleError);

    return x;

  }
private makeHeader(method : string){
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'

  });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return options;
}
```

> But I get **no response**/ Blank(no json results) and **status code** is 200 OK. But the response is **empty**.

But If I change the url to `www.site.com/test.php` I get a response from a **PHP**. So I know that my http request code is not the problem.

> Is this problem related to the JSP/Spring server? and How would I get the JSON response

Comment: Not easy to say given what you have here. Note that passing an unbound method as a callback is a dangerous practice.

Comment: Sorry If don't follow. What do you mean by unbound method?

Comment: Look up "dynamic `this` binding in JavaScript". Then you will have just one more reason to doubt the angular tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess based on the information you provided is that you are having cross origin request issues. Please make sure in your controller you have allowed cross origin requests for the method. Just anotate the method with

```
@CrossOrigin
```

This will basically indicate to your server that should respond to the browser that it accepts requests from any domain. You can also restrict the domains you want to allow. More here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html

If you don't enable this on the server the browser will not complete the request due to security policies.